# How to make popUp not submit form on startup?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0,
I have a createInsert button that has ShowPopUp Behavior operation included. In the popUp I have inserted a form whose attributes will be clean from the createInsert operation. When I click the button the popUp shows up all right but showing an error about the mandatory fields of the form. The fields of the form of course are empty because I just opened it. So I think that the popUp is autoSubmiting the form at the starting point.

Does anyone have an idea how to stop it from doing this?

I have changed the createInsert button PartialSubmit property to false but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution. The popUp was not submitting anything actually but during the CreateInsert operation the iterator opens a new row in every related component within that page (form, table etc). So when my popUp opened up with the new form fields, a new row was being  created in the back-stage in my read-only table. I changed the iterator in a new one from another Application Module for each case and everything is fine now.